# Combine exit data for several pages

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics, I want to compile exit page data on several URLs that all end on the same subpage.

I have thousands of pages that all have a unique URL but I want to see how many users exited on for example the “age-check” (and there are several sub-pages like these).

For example, Google Analytics is telling me:

- `example.com/uniquecodeA/age-check` - 1 exit
- `example.com/uniquecodeB/age-check`  - 1 exit

I want to have statistics 2 exits on `/age-check/` pages.

Is that possible, and how?

Comment: Just use a regular expression-based filter and pay attention to the totals.